# Collection referencing multiple collections

Tags: mongodb

I want to have a collection with multiple fields referencing multiple collections, something like it:

```
var comboSchema = new Schema({
  oneId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "One" },
  twoId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Two" },
  threeId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Three" },
  components: {
    id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Component"},
    amount: {type: Number}
  }
}
```

I know I can use `$lookup` and `aggregate` to get data, but it looks like it works only on a single field in a collection?

Any help? Thank you! :-)

Comment: Really not sure what the question is here. Seems to have a built in answer where you are expecting someone to agree with you. You might consider instead explaining what you need to achieve if you want advice on how to structure data.

Comment: @NeilLunn Question is: how would you get data from such a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a model sample using the ref, the ref key in the object will take the name of the model in which you are referencing

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: 1
    },
    mediatype: {
        type: String,
        required: 1
    },
    media: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    likes: {
        type: [{
            userid: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            }
        }]
    },
    comments: {
        type: [{
            userid: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            },
            comment: String
        }]
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Post = mongoose.model('post', postSchema)

module.exports = Post
```

so you can then populate it like `Post.find().populate('user')`